# Linux: Make an invisible xwindow visible

Tags: x11, xlib

When running (many many versions) of [Zoom](https://zoom.us) on arch linux, the annotation toolbar does not appear.
I am using Gnome.
I have submitted many bug reports, but I have a feeling the problem is very specific to my setup and I am trying to find a workaround.

Using the code below I have found a window with the promising name "annotate_toolbar".
How can I make it visible using python-xlib or any other tool?

```
from pprint import pprint

from Xlib import display
from Xlib.protocol.request import QueryTree

d = display.Display()
root = d.screen().root

query: QueryTree = root.query_tree()
for c in query.children:  # type: display.Window
    name = c.get_wm_name()
    if name != "annotate_toolbar":
        continue
    print(c, name)
    pprint(c.get_geometry()._data)
    pprint(c.get_attributes()._data)
```

Output:

```
<class 'Xlib.display.Window'>(0x04401b09) annotate_toolbar
{'border_width': 0,
 'depth': 32,
 'height': 43,
 'root': <<class 'Xlib.display.Window'> 0x00000174>,
 'sequence_number': 129,
 'width': 678,
 'x': 621,
 'y': 107}
{'all_event_masks': 6463615,
 'backing_bit_planes': 4294967295,
 'backing_pixel': 0,
 'backing_store': 0,
 'bit_gravity': 1,
 'colormap': <<class 'Xlib.xobject.colormap.Colormap'> 0x04401b08>,
 'do_not_propagate_mask': 0,
 'map_is_installed': 0,
 'map_state': 2,
 'override_redirect': 1,
 'save_under': 1,
 'sequence_number': 130,
 'visual': 173,
 'win_class': 1,
 'win_gravity': 1,
 'your_event_mask': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically want an Xlib programming solution, you could try `xdotool` on the command line.
I don't have or want `Zoom` on my box, so I can't test it directly but if I use `Calculator` as a stand-in:

```
xdotool search --name "Calculator" getwindowname windowactivate
```

brings up the Calculator, if it's running.

There are many other options available to you via `xdotool`, along with command chaining.

```
Usage: xdotool <cmd> <args>
Available commands:
  getactivewindow
  getwindowfocus
  getwindowname
  getwindowpid
  getwindowgeometry
  getdisplaygeometry
  search
  selectwindow
  help
  version
  behave
  behave_screen_edge
  click
  getmouselocation
  key
  keydown
  keyup
  mousedown
  mousemove
  mousemove_relative
  mouseup
  set_window
  type
  windowactivate
  windowfocus
  windowkill
  windowclose
  windowmap
  windowminimize
  windowmove
  windowraise
  windowreparent
  windowsize
  windowunmap
  set_num_desktops
  get_num_desktops
  set_desktop
  get_desktop
  set_desktop_for_window
  get_desktop_for_window
  get_desktop_viewport
  set_desktop_viewport
  exec
  sleep
```